# How to convert .rda to .pmml and use it in Python

Tags: python, r, pmml

I've got myself a neural network model in .rda format that is already trained, and I'm not sure how to convert it to .pmml so that I can use it as a predictive engine in Python. Once this is done, which libraries should I install to allow the pmml file to be used in Python? Are there any special interactions I should be aware of?

-UPDATE- I installed r2pmml into my RStudio, and I was wondering if its possible to load a model from .rda format and instantly export it without having to train it. Can this be done?

-UPDATE 2- Managed to convert .Rda to .pmml successfully. I have a list of 0/1 vectors to use with the pmml file, (53,850 1's and 0's); how do I run the list through the predictive model in Python? One of the suggestions was to use Augustus.

Comment: Check this for [PMML](https://code.google.com/archive/p/augustus/) file to be used in python.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start working on it as soon as I've figured out how to convert the rda file into pmml.

Comment: can you tell me. what is the solution you have figured out?

Comment: I have yet to find a solution - I'm still not sure how to convert .rda to .pmml, though I'm sure I'll find something. I'll keep you updated on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .rda file contains the model object in a R-specific serialization data format. You should be able to de-serialize it using the [`readRDS(rds_path)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) method, and then invoke the `r2pmml(model, pmml_path)` method.

Training a model, and serializing it into a RDS file:

```
library("randomForest")
rf = randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)
saveRDS(rf, "rf.rds")
```

De-serializing the model from the RDS file, and exporting it into a PMML file:

```
library("r2pmml")
rf_clone = readRDS("rf.rds")
r2pmml(rf_clone, "rf.pmml")
```

Comment: Apparently, there's no Java executable installed in your computer (did you read through the "requirements" and "installation" sections of the r2pmml package?). You can replace the `r2pmml` function call with the "standard" `pmml` function call then: `library("pmml")` followed by `saveXML(pmml(rf_clone), "rf.pmml")`

Comment: I managed to do it using the standard pmml library. Not sure why r2pmml wasn't working as I have Java installed on my computer - maybe it wasn't detecting it properly?